# reverse lookup in a map

Tags: dictionary, clojure, key-value

I have to extract a key from a map using a value. Is there a way to do this other than implementing reverse lookup myself?

Comment: What if 2 or more keys have the same value? Do you need just one of them, or all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
(some #(if (= (val %) your-val) (key %)) your-map)
```

Answer (score 26):

I think that `map-invert` is the right way to do this.

[From the docs:](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.set/map-invert)

```
;; Despite being in clojure.set, this has nothing to do with sets. 

user=> (map-invert {:a 1, :b 2})
{2 :b, 1 :a}

;; If there are duplicate keys, one is chosen:

user=> (map-invert {:a 1, :b 1})
{1 :b}

;; I suspect it'd be unwise to depend on which key survives the clash.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can reverse a map really easily with a 2-line function:

```
(defn reverse-map [m]
  (into {} (map (fn [[a b]] [b a]) m)))

(def a {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})

(reverse-map a)
=> {1 :a, 3 :c, 2 :b}

((reverse-map a) 1)
=> :a
```

Comment: Note: For all intensive purposes, what the map `{:a 1 :b 1}` becomes is undefined.

Comment: @Jeremy: it's not strictly undefined, you will reliably get a reverse lookup of either `{1 :a}` or `{1 :b}` (which one you get depends on the internal ordering of the hashmap). But I agree that if you have duplicate values, you probably want to give this some special treatment.

Comment: Yeah. All I meant was that it should not be relied upon. Also, small maps that are PersistentArrayMaps can have *predictable* (not necessarily expected) behavior until they are coerced into a PersistentHashMap. But again, it's not something that should be relied upon.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ClojureScript or you need one more alternative :)

`(zipmap (vals m) (keys m))`

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
(defn reverse-map [m]                                                                                                                          
  (apply hash-map  (mapcat reverse m)))  

(defn reverse-lookup [m k]                                                                                                                     
  (ffirst (filter (comp #{k} second) m)))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the keys, it is better to just invert the map, but collect the old keys in a set / list etc...

```
(defn map-inverse [m]
  (reduce (fn [m' [k v]] (update m' v clojure.set/union #{k})) {} m))

(defn map-inverse [m]
  (reduce (fn [m' [k v]] (update m' v conj k)) {} m))
```